# Saving objects to a list

Tags: r, list

i have 210 time series flow daily data which i have made to xts and save them to a list called ''xtslist'' from where i call each of my time series data. I have made also a function called "submonth". I give the time series data and the month and rerurns all the data for the first time series data and first month for example. I want to fit some distributions to flow_data_per_month and to take the results for each month and time series data from a list. I have made this below:

```
distrlist=vector("list",data_length)
for(i in 1:1){
  flow_data=xtslist[[i]]
  for(j in 1:12){
  flow_data_per_month=sub_month(x=flow_data, Month=j)
  flow_data_per_monthz=flow_data_per_month[flow_data_per_month>0] 
  fit_gam=elmgamma(x = as.vector(flow_data_per_monthz), plot = 1) # Fit the Gamma distribution
  fit_wei=elmweibull(x = as.vector(flow_data_per_monthz), plot = 1) # Fit the Weibull distribution
  fit_lnorm=elmlnorm(x = as.vector(flow_data_per_monthz), plot = 1) # Fit the Lognormal distribution
  gam=fit_gam$Eval$MSEquant
  wei=fit_wei$Eval$MSEquant
  lnorm=fit_lnorm$Eval$MSEquant
  results=cbind(namelist[i],j,gam,wei,lnorm)
  colnames(results)=c("Station","Month","gamma","weibull","lognormal")
  }
  
  
distrlist[[i]][[j]]=results  

}
```

After running this code when i put distrlist[[1]][[12]] for example giving:

```
     Station                              Month gamma              weibull            lognormal         
[1,] "Po River at Pontelagoscuro (Italy)" "12"  "66840.6570263113" "114710.262863894" "21237.2469353958"
```

But if i put distrlist[[1]][[11]] or the others months giving NULL.
What i do wrong???
i would appreciate if anyone could help me

Comment: `distrlist[[i]][[j]]=results` should be in the `for (i in 1:12)` loop, which is not the case, see first `}`

Comment: Yes that was it!!! Thank you very much Waldi!!!